# How to free such pointers?

Tags: delphi, pointers, memory-management, delphi-7

My custom control has pointers to parent but I don't know how to free those pointers in destructor.

variables:

```
{Pointers}
  Form: TForm;
  GeneralPointer: Pointer;
  Frame: ^TImage;
```

the constructor:

```
constructor TViOS.Create(var ImageOutput: TImage);
begin
inherited Create;

  Form := TForm(GetParentForm(TControl(ImageOutput)));
  GeneralPointer := Addr(ImageOutput);
  Frame := GeneralPointer;
...
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are allocating any RAM by creating anything -- looks like you're just setting pointers to already existing objects, right?  Can't you just set the variables to `nil` in the destructor?

Comment: @James L. Okay, I get it now =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you aren't *creating* any of the objects in the constructor, you don't need to `Free` them in the destructor -- just set them to nil.

```
destructor TViOS.Destroy;
begin
  Form := nil;
  GeneralPointer := nil;
  Frame := nil;
end;
```

Comment: Why bother setting the pointers to nil? I'd just delete the entire destructor.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others said, your code can use some cleanup:

```
Form: TForm;
GeneralPointer: Pointer;
Frame: TImage;
```

.

```
constructor TViOS.Create(ImageOutput: TImage);
begin
  inherited Create;
  Form := GetParentForm(ImageOutput) as TForm;
  GeneralPointer := ImageOutput;
  Frame := ImageOutput;
  ...
end;
```